# javascript API call results in old data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

I have a weather web api,which I need  to show weather report of current city in website.Whenever the code calls in the API, it results only in old data.Data never changes and when I run the web API URL on the browser it results exactly what I want.
Please help me what could be the reason for the cached data.

webAPI

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=26.894049&lon=80.942686&mode=json
```

my code

```
$.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + 'mode=json&rand=' + Math.random(), function (data) {
    var wind = {};
    var temp = {};
    wind = data.wind;
    temp = data.weather;
    var clouds = '%' + data.clouds.all;
    var description = data.weather[0].description;
    var temp = data.main.temp - 273.15;
    var humidity = data.main.humidity + '%';
    var icon = data.weather[0].icon;
    weatherImg = "<img height=\"45\" width=\"45\" style=\"border: medium none; width: 45px; height: 45px;position:relative;top:-10px; background: url('http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png') repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;\" alt=\"title\" src=\"http://openweathermap.org/images/transparent.png\">";
    document.getElementById('weatherImg').innerHTML = weatherImg;
    document.getElementById('current_temp').innerHTML = (temp) + '&deg;C';
    document.getElementById('current_wind').innerHTML = ' ; ' + wind.speed + 'Km/h';
    document.getElementById('city_name').innerHTML = data.name;
});
```

Comment: Can you fiddle your code please?

Comment: Tried with some other weather APIs ? showing same result?

Comment: this is all the code.I guess there is some code needed in my ajax call

Comment: nope didnt tried with other web apis

Answer (score 0):

tested your code working fine for me some time api response is slow but other than that every thing looks ok to me

```
htttp://jsfiddle.net/navneetccna/un2u5j0v
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the url in your script prefix mode with &. You should throw this in a fiddle / be more specific. You say you're getting old data. Are you getting an old JSON response that doesn't change at all, or infrequently?

Comment: well thats not the problem, it will only refresh the API URL